What happens if you are affected by the Freedom of Movement spell and are then subject to an elemental's Whirlwind or Vortex?
In Pathfinder First Edition, the spell "Freedom of Movement" reads as follows:

This spell enables you or a creature you touch to move and attack
normally for the duration of the spell, even under the influence of
magic that usually impedes movement, such as paralysis, solid fog,
slow, and web. All combat maneuver checks made to grapple the target
automatically fail. The subject automatically succeeds on any combat
maneuver checks and Escape Artist checks made to escape a grapple or a
pin.
The spell also allows the subject to move and attack normally while
underwater, even with slashing weapons such as axes and swords or with
bludgeoning weapons such as flails, hammers, and maces, provided that
the weapon is wielded in the hand rather than hurled. The freedom of
movement spell does not, however, grant water breathing.

The Air Elemental's Whirlwind abilty (which the water elemental vortex abiity is also based on) reads as follows:

Some creatures can transform themselves into whirlwinds [...] Another
creature might be caught in the whirlwind if it touches or enters the
whirlwind, or if the whirlwind moves into or through the creature’s
space. A creature in whirlwind form cannot make its normal attacks and
does not threaten the area around it.
Creatures one or more size categories smaller than the whirlwind might
take damage when caught in the whirlwind (generally damage equal to
the monster’s slam attack for a creature of its size) and may be
lifted into the air. An affected creature must succeed on a Reflex
save (DC 10 + half monster’s HD + the monster’s Strength modifier)
when it comes into contact with the whirlwind or take damage as if it
were hit by the whirlwind creature’s slam attack. It must also succeed
on a second Reflex save or be picked up bodily and held suspended in
the powerful winds, automatically taking the indicated damage each
round. A creature that can fly is allowed a Reflex save each round to
escape the whirlwind. The creature still takes damage but can leave if
the save is successful.
Creatures trapped in the whirlwind cannot move except to go where the
whirlwind carries them or to escape the whirlwind. Trapped creatures
can otherwise act normally, but must succeed on a concentration check
(DC 15 + spell level) to cast a spell. Creatures caught in the
whirlwind take a –4 penalty to Dexterity and a –2 penalty on attack
rolls. The whirlwind can have only as many creatures trapped inside at
one time as will fit inside the whirlwind’s volume. The whirlwind can
eject any carried creatures whenever it wishes as a free action,
depositing them in its space.

How do these things interact? Let's say first you have freedom of movement cast on you, and then  you are subject to the effects of an elemental's whirlwind or vortex? How would this affect you?
Would it still pick you up? While picked up, can you move and act normally? Does it prevent you from being moved by it? Does the Whirlwind qualify as "magic that usually impedes movement, such as paralysis"?

Pathfinder had a golden opportunity to clarify the freedom of movement spell and, instead, left it the same as it was in D&D 3.5 (cf. here and here). That means you may be interested in answers to this question.

thanks, still nto sure about my specific interaction that came up though. We eneded up ruling that it did pick you up on the second failed save and deal damage, but you cna just walk out fo it on your turn as you can act normally with FoM. It can follow you can keep ding damage, but it can't impede you. I am not sure if taht's the right call, but seems most likely it is

Much of freedom of movement is up to the GM
Among the first questions I posed to this site over a decade ago was this one asking about freedom of movement effects. The controversy hasn't lessened; the spell's as vague in Pathfinder as it was in its antecedent D&D 3.5, and with Paizo ceasing publication of the original Pathfinder, freedom of movement is likely to remain officially vague forever. Really, at this point, I suspect that literally any call that a GM makes about freedom of movement will have its advocates and detractors online—even community consensus on freedom of movement is that rare. Thus what effect a freedom of movement effect has is almost entirely and whimsically up to the GM.
Nonetheless, because that isn't particularly useful, below is a longer look at the situation in the question.
A Large air elemental versus a human fighter that's already the subject of a freedom of movement effect
In the Castle of Smoke and Fire's vast anteroom, the human fighter Rellik encounters the hostile Large air elemental Gninnips. Gninnips's initiative result exceeds Rellik's. Gninnips takes a standard action to activate the supernatural ability whirlwind. Gninnips becomes a 5-ft.-at-the-base, 20-ft.-at-the-top, 40-ft.-tall whirlwind that's (at least) Large. It then takes a move action to fly some distance and ends its movement with part of its whirlwind form occupying the entirety of Rellik's space. (It's allowed to do this as a creature in whirlwind form, and a creature in whirlwind form doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity. The GM ignores the effects of the debris cloud. This is already overcomplicated.)
Rellik is in but not caught by the whirlwind. He makes a Ref save (DC 18). He fails. Gninnips's whirlwind form deals Rellik 1d8+4 points of damage.
Here it's possible for the GM to rule that this interaction ends on first principles. If the freedom of movement effect is, for example, imagined as (among other things) a nigh-frictionless  coating, attempts by the wind to take hold of Rellik fail, the same way anything trying to make any long-term contact with him would. The GM can say, "You feel the wind whipping around you, but you are unaffected by it," and be done. (The GM may add, "You'll suffer normal penalties for being in the whirlwind, though." Or the GM may not. I dunno. Look again at that debris cloud maybe, too?)
Assuming that the GM doesn't say that Rellik's freedom of movement effect renders him immune to the whirlwind, Rellik makes a second Ref save (DC 18 also). He fails again. Rellik is "picked up bodily and held suspended in the powerful winds" of Gninnips the whirlwind. As the freedom of movement spell's exceptions for underwater and grapples don't apply, the GM rules that Rellik is suspended 20 ft. in the air. (How high is actually unclear, but this ersatz GM likes the levitate spell for comparison; a total of 20 ft. up or down each turn—starting this one—seems fair. Astute readers will note that an air elemental's whirlwind ability could've itself used some clarification.)
Now it's Rellik's turn. He's 20 ft. up, caught in the whirlwind and can't fly. Due to the freedom of movement effect, though, Rellik can "move and attack normally…, even [if he's] under the influence of magic" like Gninnips's whirlwind ability, but the GM must determine what this means. The game doesn't say. Here are some examples:

Narrow: While in the whirlwind Rellik suffers a –4 penalty to Dexterity and a –2 penalty on attack rolls. The GM rules that while Rellik can still move normally, there's nowhere for Rellik's land speed to take him. The GM rules that if nothing interferes then Rellik will remain suspended for the whirlwind's duration.

Broad: While in the whirlwind Rellik suffers a –4 penalty to Dexterity and a –2 penalty on attack rolls. The GM rules that Rellik can move normally using his land speed, but because there's nowhere for his land speed to take him, he'll immediately fall when he tries. However, once a surface's underneath him (like the ground), he can use his land speed to actually move normally, even in squares covered by the whirlwind. (The GM may use those debris cloud rules now, though.)

Expansive: While in the whirlwind Rellik suffers a –4 penalty to Dexterity, but the GM rules that Rellik can make attacks from within the whirlwind at no penalty because freedom of movement says that the subject can "attack normally," and a penalty isn't normal. The GM then rules that Rellik can use his normal land speed to freely traverse the entirety of the whirlwind's expanse, including up or down, as if parts of it were solid and others weren't, determined by Rellik in the moment. Rellik can even move in and out of the whirlwind if he wants, but if he exits the whirlwind while above the ground, he will fall. (Whereupon: debris cloud!)


A reader might hold an opinion that freedom of movement works in a way described above or have an entirely different opinion; the above list isn't meant to be comprehensive. Because there's hardly any guidance on freedom of movement, claiming that a reading is outright wrong according to the rules as presented in the text is not without peril. How a freedom of movement effect works in a particular campaign really is up to the GM. Pick your favorite or make up your own and go.
In sum, a comment from the question's author said that the ruling at the table was that, essentially, Gninnips's whirlwind could pick up and suspend Rellik, but that Rellik could use his land speed to exit the whirlwind (cf. Broad, above). That's as good a call as any. I urge the GM to write down that ruling in the campaign's notes so that later freedom of movement rulings will be consistent with that one.

Note: Among others, how freedom of movement interacts with whirlwind is discussed in a D&D 3.5 EN World thread in 2003 here and in Pathfinder threads on Reddit in 2015 here and 2021 here.

Thatnks for this detailed lsit. I don't even think the ruling involved any penalty as "move normally" was considered to coutner that, The other thing that's different is that it was not a whirlwind but a vortex and the PCs were udnerwater (whcih is hy they had freedom of movement in the first place. I don't know if this matters in the interpretation. Freedom fo movemnt specifically says you can move and attack without penalty in water, and the vortex is water (that happens to be moving). In either case it seems like the ruling was in between the broad and expansive above.

@AndrewADeMarco You're welcome. Sorry about the whirlwind/vortex thing. I don't think it matters except that it's safer to exit a vortex than a whirlwind! And, yeah, if you attribute the -4 penalty to Dex as inhibiting moving normally (which I hadn't even considered), that'd probably lean you toward the expansive reading. That's legit, though, especially if everybody's having fun. (I do wonder: Does attack and move normally mean ignoring bonuses and penalties? Bonuses aren't normal either, right?)

hmmm, I cntrl-f for "free" on all thsoe links and could nto find any mention fo freedom of movement on any of them

@AndrewADeMarco The 2003 and 2015 threads are more about how the whirlwind works so that opinions can be formed about its interaction with freedom of movement. However, the 2021 thread is totally about freedom of movement.

and yeah, we didn't stop it from picking people up, because the spell doesn't say it stops forced movement, only that it prevents your movement from being impeded. So I would assume a creature can move you on its turn (assuming they can with an ability like this as FoM prevents grapple), but on your turn you can jsut walk out of the effect, and any penalties to you moving or attacking normally are ignored. Liek you way it is so vaguely worded it is hard to know what the itnent was

ah yes, I missed that last link. I ahve read that one before yes. Even on there there are differering opinions. I think ti comes down to "move and attack normally" and what that means.

Any hints into the RAI from the designers or were they perpetually silent on it?

@AndrewADeMarco A largely useless FAQ entry then perpetual silence. Were there more, it'd be here.

I will wait another day and choose your answer if nothing better hits then
